# check if collection find return a cursor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor code needs to check if a certain document exist in the collection by checking if a cursor is returned, and if no cursor returned then the document does not exist. but it always returns true even if there is no value "alosh" for the `text` field in any of the documents in the collection
.
Why and how can it be fixed? Thanks

```
    if (myCollection.find({text: 'alosh'}, {limit: 1})) {console.log('found');}
```

**edit**
The reason I did not use `colllection.findOne` is my understanding that it is much slower according to [this post](https://blog.serverdensity.com/checking-if-a-document-exists-mongodb-slow-findone-vs-find/)

Comment: Fair enough on your edit, but it's worth mentioning that Meteor basically does `find().limit(1)` for `findOne` anyway (see [definition](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/f0404b6e0d50ce80949f896d346d5b2557da5494/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js#L122)). And once you've added the `count()`, it's really not clear that you're making any significant savings (see speed test [here](https://gist.github.com/jmikola/5208918))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a count. A cursor is always going to be a truthy value as the cursor itself is returned. You need to check the records contained in the cursor so...

```
if (myCollection.find({text: 'alosh'}, {limit: 1}).count()) {
    console.log('found');
}
```

Because no docs returned is 0 and 0 is falsey this should only return when documents are found

Answer (score 1):

Idea for solution:

You want to understand if there is a document with a certain value for a certain property. You could use:

```
if(myCollection.findOne({text: 'alosh'})){
console.log("found");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongo cursors seem to behave the same as arrays in that an empty cursor (and an empty array) evaluate to `true`.

So `!![] //true` and `!!collection.find({text : "alosh"}) //true`.

BUT `collection.findOne({text : "alosh"})` will fail your `if` - so use that instead

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone